# Strange exception when using groupBy in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table with a few columns, two of them are: vendingMachineId (which are repeated) and each one has a timestamp.

I want to get latest timestamp for each vendingMachineId so I did this:

```
def getLastReading(assetIds: List[Int])(implicit db: Session): Map[Int, String] = {
    val vmrps = (((for {
      vmrp <- VendingMachineReadingProducts if (vmrp.vendingMachineId inSet assetIds)
    } yield (vmrp.vendingMachineId, vmrp.timestamp)).sortBy(_._2.desc)).groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2))).map {
      case (all, q) => all._1 -> all._2
    }.list

    vmrps map {
      case (assetId, timestamp) => {
        assetId -> (new SimpleDateFormat(DateTimeUtils.defaultDateTimeFormat)).format(timestamp)
      }
    } toMap
  }
```

The issue is that I receive a strange exception:

```
scala.slick.SlickException: Unexpected node Ref @20339870 -- SQL prefix: select 
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.toComprehension(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:75) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.expr(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:285) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver$QueryBuilder.expr(PostgresDriver.scala:55) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.buildSelectPart(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:155) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same thing, but see [this](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/110) slick issue. It is already fixed in upstream, but the 1.0.0 version still has the problem.